# Change icon order for .ico file

Tags: editing, icons, ordering

.ico file contains icon with various size in particular order. Is there any utility to change this order in .ico file?

Comment: Any particular reason you wish to do this?

Comment: @SamB - I've had issues in Visual Studio when images are ordered small to large and I set that icon for my application. The small icon seems to be used everywhere (most noticeably, the taskbar). Although maybe it just always takes the first image in my case and it's downscaling nicely if I start with large...

Answer (score 2):

My favorite (free) icon editor is [IcoFX](http://icofx.ro/). There is [a related discussion about reordering icons](http://icofx.ro/forum/viewtopic.php?f=4&t=9), but I don't know if it has actually been implemented. I'll follow up after I check.

Comment: I promised to follow up: in the current version (1.6.4) it is **not** possible to rearrange icons. As wonderful as that program is, this is something that's missing. I don't really understand why you would want to do this, but the option should be there nonetheless.

Answer (score 1):

http://www.axialis.com/iconworkshop/

Comment: Doesn't have a reorder feature.

Answer (score 1):

[Microangelo](http://www.microangelo.us/) is a good shareware that can do that.

Answer (score 1):

It might happen that compression (introduced with Vista for 256 pixel icons) affects icon order. Try turning off compression to move big icons to the front.